# Modify tags Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to modify every tag in python using beautiful soup. There are a bunch of different td tags, and I am trying to turn every td tag with a certain attribute into something else. For example, there is

```
<td class="station"> ... </td>
```

the tag above I do not want to change, but then there is

```
<td class="menuitem"> ... </td>
```

and I want to modify all of these

```
<td class="menuitem"> ... </td>
```

to something like

```
<body class="menuitem"> ... </body>
```

And just to clarify I want every

```
<td class="menuitem"> ... </td>
```

changed, not just the first one.

Thanks in advance for the help!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I'd just do:

```
for tag in soup.select('td.menuitem'):
    tag.name = 'body' # mutates the tag in `soup`!
```

(using a css selector here, equivalent to `soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'menuitem'})`)

demo:

```
s = '''<td class="station"> no touchies </td><td class="menuitem"> foo </td><td class="menuitem"> bar </td><td class="menuitem"> baz </td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

soup
Out[111]: <html><body><td class="station"> no touchies </td><td class="menuitem"> foo </td><td class="menuitem"> bar </td><td class="menuitem"> baz </td></body></html>

for tag in soup.select('td.menuitem'):
    tag.name = 'body'

soup
Out[113]: <html><body><td class="station"> no touchies </td><body class="menuitem"> foo </body><body class="menuitem"> bar </body><body class="menuitem"> baz </body></body></html>
```